Gridview.count inside Column and wrapped by SingleChildScrollView crops text due to shrinkWrap: true
Gridview.count inside Column and wrapped by SingleChildScrollView crops button text due to shrinkWrap: true. Without shrinkWrap: true, flutter throws an error, shown bellow.
I've already tried changing physics: BouncingScrollPhysics() property to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() inside Gridview.count but it throws the same error:

The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical
viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
or Wrap instead. Otherwise, consider using a CustomScrollView to concatenate arbitrary slivers into
a single scrollable.

It's pretty self-explanatory, but I've already tried creating a layout with rows and columns, but I cannot make them to get the same height and width of the biggest choice button (which is what I want). That's why I tried using Gridview.count.
Obs.: Of course, I cannot give a fixed height to the Column because the text size inside the buttons is variable.
Here is the code snippet (look how text choice 4 is cropped):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  List<Widget> choiceButtons = [
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('choice 1: this size this size this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
          'choice 2: this size this size this size this size this size this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('choice 3: this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
          'choice 4: this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size '),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('test'),
                  Center(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 1 / .4,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                      children: List.generate(choiceButtons.length, (index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: choiceButtons[index],
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('test'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



What could I do?

is there any image that shows your expected result?

You probably have to manually layout children in the render layer in this case.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = ScrollController();

  List<Widget> choiceButtons = [
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('choice 1: this size this size this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('choice 2: this size this size this size this size this size this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('choice 3: this size'),
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text(
          'choice 4: this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size this size '),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Scrollbar(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('test'),
                  Center(
                    child: MyGridLayout(
                      children: List.generate(choiceButtons.length, (index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: choiceButtons[index],
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text('test'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyGridLayout extends MultiChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const MyGridLayout({
    super.key,
    super.children,
  });

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return MyGridLayoutRenderObject();
  }
}

class MyGridLayoutRenderObject extends RenderBox
    with
        ContainerRenderObjectMixin<RenderBox, MultiChildLayoutParentData>,
        RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin<RenderBox, MultiChildLayoutParentData> {
  @override
  void setupParentData(RenderBox child) {
    if (child.parentData is! MultiChildLayoutParentData) {
      child.parentData = MultiChildLayoutParentData();
    }
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    double maxHeight = 0;
    RenderBox? child = firstChild;
    while (child != null) {
      child.layout(
          BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / 2, maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight / 2),
          parentUsesSize: true);
      maxHeight = max(maxHeight, child.size.height);
      child = childAfter(child);
    }
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    child = firstChild;
    while (child != null) {
      final childParentData = child.parentData as MultiChildLayoutParentData;
      if (column == 2) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
      }
      childParentData.offset = Offset(
        column * constraints.maxWidth / 2,
        row * maxHeight + (maxHeight - child.size.height) / 2,
      );
      column++;
      child = childAfter(child);
    }
    size = Size(constraints.maxWidth, maxHeight * (row + 1));
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    defaultPaint(context, offset);
  }
}

Or use Boxy library if you want to reduce some boilerplate
import 'package:boxy/boxy.dart';

class MyBoxyGridLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBoxyGridLayout({
    super.key,
    required this.children,
  });

  final List<Widget> children;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBoxy(
      delegate: MyGridLayoutDelegate(),
      children: children,
    );
  }
}

class MyGridLayoutDelegate extends BoxyDelegate {
  @override
  Size layout() {
    double maxHeight = 0;
    for (BoxyChild child in children) {
      child.layout(
          BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth / 2, maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight / 2));
      maxHeight = max(maxHeight, child.size.height);
    }
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    for (BoxyChild child in children) {
      if (column == 2) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
      }
      child.position(Offset(
        column * constraints.maxWidth / 2,
        row * maxHeight + (maxHeight - child.size.height) / 2,
      ));
      column++;
    }
    return Size(constraints.maxWidth, maxHeight * (row + 1));
  }
}


Just remove  childAspectRatio: 1 / .4, and its working.
